# Having trouble keep KDCircularProgress view inside parent view

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, kdcircularprogress

I tried to use KDCircularProgress in my project in progressView class which inherent UIView class

```
init(frame: CGRect) {

    progress = KDCircularProgress(frame: frame)

    letter = "A"

    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupCircularProgress(frame: frame)

    UILabel()
        .add(to: self)
        .layout { (make) in
            make.center.equalToSuperview()
    }.config { (view) in
        view.text = letter
    }   

}
```

and the setupCircularProgress function:

```
func setupCircularProgress(frame:CGRect) {
    progress.clockwise = true
    progress.set(colors: randomColor(hue: .random, luminosity: .light))
    progress.glowMode = .forward
    progress.glowAmount = 0
    progress.center = self.center
    progress.trackColor = UIColor.white


    self.addSubview(progress)

    progress.animate(fromAngle: 0, toAngle: 360, duration: 5, completion: { completed in
        if completed {
            print("animation stopped, completed")
            self.removeFromSuperview()
        } else {
            print("animation stopped, was interrupted")
        }
    })
}
```

In viewController

```
LetterView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50)).add(to: self.playView!)
```

but it shows like this
[showed view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPbi2.jpg)

I had no idea why the KDCircularProgress is outside the frame, and only the textLabel was in the right place.
And there is no logic where the KDCircularProgress view will appear according to the assigned frame.

If anyone has dealt with this situation and problem, please tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Funny I get the answer right after I asked the question :)

In my custom UIView, I should init the KDCircularProgress like this

```
 progress = KDCircularProgress(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))
```

because the position is relative to the UIView.